# Updating NuGet packages in Visual Studio causes the project build to fail

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget

In the Updates tab of `NuGet Package Manager` in VS2015 I saw updates available for about 25 already installed packages. Most of the updates indicated an update from 1.0 to 1.1. So, I decided to update them. But, after the updates, when I tried to Rebuild solution the build failed with the following errors. I ran `dotnet restore` command as suggested by one error below but the build still fails with same errors. I installed the latest NuGet from [here](http://www.nuget.org/). I double clicked on each error to go to the place where error occurs but could not figure out what needs to be done. **Question:** How can I resolve the following errors so I can rebuild the solution again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating ASP.NET Core packages dependencies to use the new 1.1.0 versions means moving to .NET Core 1.1, that requires some more modification in the project.

You need to install the .NET Core 1.1 and upgrade your project from .NET Core 1.0 to .NET Core 1.1.

Also keep in mind, that new `.csproj` format has been provided as replace for `project.json`. You may still use `project.json`, but if you would like to migrate to new format, you need to move to VS 2017 or VS Code, as VS 2015 does not support it.

See [Announcing .Net Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/) and [Announcing ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1).

Comment: I followed the 3 steps described in your link [Announcing ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/). But still the exact same errors. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: @nam it is difficult to say without knowing what exactly you have modified/changed. Migration is not a one-click process and different changes need to be done as you already have noticed. Also, note that `global.json`  sdk section should be updated as well... To summarize:   at least please update your question with current `project.json`  and additional migration steps that you did.